# Simplifying $e^{-R/8300} = e^{-T/8300}(1-e^{-2.996(5000-T)/1000})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, arithmetic

I'm here asking this question simply to know how this author derived his answer in the article ["Correlation of C-14 Age with the Biblical Time Scale" (PDF link via grisda.org)](https://grisda.org/assets/public/publications/origins/17056.pdf).

Solution 2 makes sense, but I just can't work out the math on the first. I'd like to see if any one in the community can help. Here are the equations:

**Original Equation** $$e^{-R/8300} = e^{-T/8300}(1-e^{-2.996(5000-T)/1000})$$

**Solution 1** $$e^{-R/8300} = e^{-T/8300} - (3.121 \times 10^{-7})(e^{+2.876T/1000})$$
I have no idea where the $3.121 \times 10^7$, or the $+2.876$ result from.  Please explain this.

**Solution 2** $$R = T + 8300 \ln (1 - e^{-2.996(5000-T)/1000})^{-1}$$

This second solution makes a hell of a lot more sense to me.  It begins by taking the natural log of both sides of the original equation.

Answer (score 1):

The constant $3.121 \cdot 10^{-7}$ can be obtained by distributing $-2.996$ in the exponential term as follows:
\begin{align}
e^{-2.996(5000-T)/1000} &= e^{-2.996(5000)/1000 + 2.996T/1000}\\
&= e^{-2.996(5000)/1000} \cdot e^{2.996T/1000}\\
&= e^{-14.98} \cdot e^{2.996T/1000}\\
&= 3.121 \cdot 10^{-7} \cdot e^{2.996T/1000}.
\end{align}
To obtain solution 1, simply use the previous result and distribute the $e^{-T/8300}$ term into the parenthesis:
\begin{align}
e^{-R/8300} &= e^{-T/8300}(1 - 3.121 \cdot 10^{-7} \cdot e^{2.996T/1000})\\
&= e^{-T/8300} - e^{-T/8300} (3.121 \cdot 10^{-7} \cdot e^{2.996T/1000})\\
&= e^{-T/8300} - 3.121 \cdot 10^{-7} \cdot e^{2.996T/1000 - T/8300}.
\end{align}
Evaluating $e^{2.996T/1000 - T/8300}$ gives $e^{2.876T/1000}$, which is the desired result.

Comment: Thanks.  That helps a lot.  Makes sense.